# Unable to click a button using xpath or id or name

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have tried various ways to click a button named "Add" in home page after login. I am unable to figure out a way. Please help.

**sample code:**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);// 1 minute 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("addArraysButton")));
driver.findElement(By.id("addArraysButton")).click();
```

**HTML file:**

```
<tr>
  <td >
    <img src="" alt="Storage Arrays" title="Storage Arrays" />
  </td>
  <td class="desc-col">
    <div class="titlepagelitesmb">Storage Arrays</div>
      <div>
        NAS and SAN arrays from many manufacturers including NetApp,
        EMC, Dell, IBM, Sun, and HP
      </div>
  </td>
  <td class="added-col">
    <img src="/images/check.none.gif" style="vertical-align: middle;"
         alt="None added" title="None added" />
    None added
  </td>
  <td class="button-col">
    <a id="addArraysButton" class="buttonRight" style="float: inherit;">
      <span>Add</span>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: please paste the error/exception u are seeing

Comment: It might happen if you are HTML is generated by javascript (Ajax) and your driver it HTMLunit .. if this is the case ,so you have to change the driver to be Ghost driver or any other that supports the javascript execution.

Comment: I am geeting exception like this:"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"addArraysButton"}
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds"

Comment: Even i have tried using JavascriptExecutor: sample code              WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("addArraysButton"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. I have got such exception because i didnt switch to the frame which has those button. After switching to a particular frame. I could find the element by id.